# Transform hierarchical data into flat table

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, hierarchical-data

I am researching about hierarchical data (as a solution to **generalize work orders**) by using ms sql.

*

> I am open to design change on my initial table and/or to add other
>   tables.

*

Here is my data

```
ID  ParentID    Type        Value
38  0           Num         327
39  38          Sector      21
40  38          Sector      22
43  40          Product     NS
44  40          Product     MS
50  40          Temp        RAS
48  44          Quantity    60
47  43          Quantity    25
41  39          Product     ARF
42  39          Product     BRF
49  39          Temp        RAS
51  39          Cible       Acarien A.
46  42          Quantity    30
52  42          Cible       Acarien B.
45  41          Quantity    20
```

I would like to transform it into :

```
Num Sector  Product Quantity
327 21      ARF     20
327 21      BRF     30
327 22      NS      25
327 22      MS      60
```

[Result using Gurwinder's answear]

```
num sector  product    quantity
327 22      MS         60
327 22      NS         25
327 21      BRF        30
327 21      BRF        Acarien B.
327 21      ARF        20
```

[Shungo's approach]

```
<root>
  <row Num="327" Sector="s2" Temp="normal" />
  <row Num="327" Sector="s2" Product="BRF" Qte="70" />
  <row Num="327" Sector="s2" Product="ARF" Qte="45" />
  <row Num="327" Sector="s1" Temp="normal" />
  <row Num="327" Sector="s1" Cible="Acarien a." />
  <row Num="327" Sector="s1" Product="NS" Qte="35" />
  <row Num="327" Sector="s1" Product="NS" Cible="Acarien b." />
  <row Num="327" Sector="s1" Product="MS" Qte="60" />
</root>
```

***Thank's a lot for your time guys.***

Comment: What was the output for the second example?

Comment: Did you try my answer? I just did it and your second example returns exactly the way you posted it... The problem in your case is two folded: 1) dynamically named columns and 2) hierarchy. Both examples are straight forward three levels deep. Is this fix?

Comment: Working to test it with ur model.

Comment: Thank you a lot, u hit the target sir [dynamically named columns and hiearchy] the problem is that the level of hierarchy is not fixed (but in 99% of cases 3)

Comment: Ismail, the results you posted are not compatible with the data you posted.  For me there is no chance to see, how your hierarchy works without a real example.

Comment: I just have an idea... give me a second...

Comment: Hi Ismail, please check my updated answer

Comment: Please recheck the post I updated it with the real data I am using

Comment: Ismail, you neglected to provide the expected output fitting to your *real data*. Your section *Result using Shnugo's answer* does not comply to the data given... I have no idea what you really need.

Comment: I really missed up, wait I am fixing this mess !! SORRY

Comment: Hi Ismail, fixing your question is a good idea :-)  In the meanwhile I updated my answer once again, please check UPDATE 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this trick?

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT,ParentID INT,Type VARCHAR(10),Value VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (1,0,'Num','327')
,(2,1,'Sector','21')
,(3,1,'Sector','22')
,(4,2,'Product','ARF')
,(5,2,'Product','BRF')
,(6,3,'Product','NS')
,(7,3,'Product','MS')
,(8,4,'Quantity','20')
,(9,5,'Quantity','30')
,(10,6,'Quantity','25')
,(11,7,'Quantity','60');

WITH recCTE AS
(
    SELECT *,0 AS HLevel,Type + N'="' + CAST(Value AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + N'" ' AS attr
    FROM @tbl WHERE ParentID=0

    UNION ALL

    SELECT t.*,r.HLevel+1,attr+t.Type + N'="' + CAST(t.Value AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + N'" '
    FROM @tbl AS t
    INNER JOIN recCTE AS r ON t.ParentID=r.ID
)
SELECT CAST(N'<row ' + attr  + N'/>' AS XML)
FROM recCTE
WHERE HLevel=3
FOR XML PATH(''),ROOT('root')
```

The result

```
<root>
  <row Num="327" Sector="22" Product="MS" Quantity="60" />
  <row Num="327" Sector="22" Product="NS" Quantity="25" />
  <row Num="327" Sector="21" Product="BRF" Quantity="30" />
  <row Num="327" Sector="21" Product="ARF" Quantity="20" />
</root>
```

This XML is easy to query... The **deepest Level** (here I took HLevel=3) can be found generically - but you'd need to provide more details...

### UPDATE

The following will not use a given depth as filter but a query to check, if a node is a **leaf-node**

I added one more row at the end

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT,ParentID INT,Type VARCHAR(100),Value VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (1,0,'Num','327')
,(2,1,'Sector','21')
,(3,1,'Sector','22')
,(4,2,'Product','ARF')
,(5,2,'Product','BRF')
,(6,3,'Product','NS')
,(7,3,'Product','MS')
,(8,4,'Quantity','20')
,(9,5,'Quantity','30')
,(10,6,'Quantity','25')
,(11,7,'Quantity','60')
,(13,11,'SomeMore','Test as fourth');

WITH recCTE AS
(
    SELECT t.*
          ,0 AS HLevel
          ,t.Type + N'="' + CAST(t.Value AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + N'" ' AS attr
          ,CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @tbl AS x WHERE x.ParentID=t.ID) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS IsLeaf
    FROM @tbl AS t WHERE ParentID=0

    UNION ALL

    SELECT t.*
          ,r.HLevel+1
          ,attr+t.Type + N'="' + CAST(t.Value AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + N'" '
          ,CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @tbl AS x WHERE x.ParentID=t.ID) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS IsLeaf
    FROM @tbl AS t
    INNER JOIN recCTE AS r ON t.ParentID=r.ID
)
SELECT CAST(N'<row ' + attr  + N'/>' AS XML)
FROM recCTE
WHERE IsLeaf=1
FOR XML PATH(''),ROOT('root')
```

The result

```
<root>
  <row Num="327" Sector="22" Product="MS" Quantity="60" SomeMore="Test as fourth" />
  <row Num="327" Sector="22" Product="NS" Quantity="25" />
  <row Num="327" Sector="21" Product="BRF" Quantity="30" />
  <row Num="327" Sector="21" Product="ARF" Quantity="20" />
</root>
```

### UPDATE 2: Using your *real data*

As you've found out alread, your question was quite a mess... Don't know what you really need, but if I run your real data through this query I'd get this:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT,ParentID INT,Type VARCHAR(100),Value VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (38,0,'Num','327')
,(39,38,'Sector','21')
,(40,38,'Sector','22')
,(43,40,'Product','NS')
,(44,40,'Product','MS')
,(50,40,'Temp','RAS')
,(48,44,'Quantity','60')
,(47,43,'Quantity','25')
,(41,39,'Product','ARF')
,(42,39,'Product','BRF')
,(49,39,'Temp','RAS')
,(51,39,'Cible','Acarien A.')
,(46,42,'Quantity','30')
,(52,42,'Cible','Acarien B.')
,(45,41,'Quantity','20');

WITH recCTE AS
(
    SELECT t.*
          ,0 AS HLevel
          ,t.Type + N'="' + CAST(t.Value AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + N'" ' AS attr
          ,CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @tbl AS x WHERE x.ParentID=t.ID) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS IsLeaf
    FROM @tbl AS t WHERE ParentID=0

    UNION ALL

    SELECT t.*
          ,r.HLevel+1
          ,attr+t.Type + N'="' + CAST(t.Value AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + N'" '
          ,CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @tbl AS x WHERE x.ParentID=t.ID) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS IsLeaf
    FROM @tbl AS t
    INNER JOIN recCTE AS r ON t.ParentID=r.ID
)
SELECT CAST(N'<row ' + attr  + N'/>' AS XML)
FROM recCTE
WHERE IsLeaf=1
FOR XML PATH(''),ROOT('root')
```

The result

```
<root>
  <row Num="327" Sector="22" Temp="RAS" />
  <row Num="327" Sector="22" Product="MS" Quantity="60" />
  <row Num="327" Sector="22" Product="NS" Quantity="25" />
  <row Num="327" Sector="21" Temp="RAS" />
  <row Num="327" Sector="21" Cible="Acarien A." />
  <row Num="327" Sector="21" Product="BRF" Quantity="30" />
  <row Num="327" Sector="21" Product="BRF" Cible="Acarien B." />
  <row Num="327" Sector="21" Product="ARF" Quantity="20" />
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot you have provided me with great help and even give answear better than what I was expecting.

Comment: I am in the phase of testing with this hierarchical table design thats why the question was messy, can you please guide me to better design what I need [Generalisation for work orders]

Comment: @IsmailKarchi please start a new question with a link to this and place a link here below my answer to alert me. A better design is - quite sure possible, as *Key-Value-Pairs* in conncetion with *self-referenced-hierarchy* seems to be over-complicated... But I do not know enough about your needs. Start a new question with more details about your actual situation (row count, use-case(s), count of groups, data integrity... and - the main question! - WHY?)

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.value num,
    t2.value sector,
    t3.value product,
    t4.value quantity
from table t1
inner join table t2
on t1.id = t2.parentid
and t1.parentid = 0
inner join table t3
on t2.id = t3.parentid
inner join table t4
on t3.id = t4.parentid;
```

Comment: Thanks, it solved this specific case only, what if I have multiple values. Let me give an example

Comment: Please post it in the question